# What happens technically when you format a partition?

Tags: 16.04, partitioning

I am trying to find out what technically happens on the disk when I re-format a partition (as opposed to deleting the partition), and what are the chances of recovering the information that was on the partition before the re-format. I ask because I accidentally re-formatted a partition and was told my stuff is irretrievable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on what type of format you did

First things first **STOP USING THIS DISK IMMEDIATELY**
if possible, make a backup, if there was a lot of free space you may be able to make use of compressing this backup
as a superuser, whenever I need to do such a backup I run `dd if=/dev/sda|pv -s 500g|bzip2|dd of=/path/to/backup`
*make sure your backup is located on a separate disk*

pv is optional, it just tells me how much data is remaining, it will slow things down, here I have told it to expect 500g of data, if you exceed this the backup wont stop, if you just use pv on it's own it will just display how much information is passing, and bzip2 will compress the backup, depending on what type of data was on the disk this will save you a lot of space but also be very time consuming, you may also remove this pipe

There are two ways to format a disk, you can rewrite the disk with zero's and place a new filesystem in there

*As disk space has been increasing, this has been becoming less and less common as it can be very time consuming*

These days, whenever you delete a file you are just deleting the reference to that file, and whenever you format a disk, you are just recreating the structure, data is simply re-written

*A fun past time of mine is buying cheap hard drives off eBay and examining their contents, most people just format the disk, they don't wipe it*

There are a number of propeitry tools available under windows to recover files from such disks, in Linux there is testdisk, scalpel and autopsy *(the sleuth kit)*

Your data will not be indexed, it will be all over the drive, often in fragments, it is possible to put all these pieces back together, but you must figure out what is important and what isn't, otherwise you will spend forever recovering that data

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The partition I accidentally re-formatted was a LUKS partition. Can testDisk recover this?

Comment: Have you written data to the disk? I can't imagine TestDisk would be very useful here, but if you were to recover a LUKS disk it would be pretty low-level work, since it's encrypted, it's going to take some effort decrypting the contents especially when the data is malformed

Comment: Does "re-formatting" constitute writing data to the disk?

Comment: Formatting a disk writes data to disk in specific locations, it would only overwrite data as needed
The difficulty with LUKS is that it is encrypted, it doesn't make it impossible, it just makes it difficult
What are you trying to retrieve, the data is still on the disk, it is just going to be scrambled, is it plain text, multimedia?

Comment: Its both multimedia and text. I assume I would probably have to de-crypt first, then look for files. The problem is how to mount it now? Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Mounting is not an option, you need to decrypt it, found this rather insightful https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1643334


Does this command work `grep -a -b -P --only-matching 'LUKS\xba\xbe' /dev/sdb`

sdb being the device location

Your filesystem is damaged, so I would not even consider mounting the filesystem as an option for recovery, you that said, you have data that you want to extract, as long as you know what you are looking for you have some luck of recovering it, all you need to do is work out how to decrypt said partition, which is going to be the difficult part

Comment: Before you put too much time and effort into recovering data off an encrypted disk that you accidentally formatted, make sure you ask yourself if it really is worth it
If the data can not be recovered at this present moment I would also consider holding on to it, as time goes by, processing power increases, new exploits are discovered, this is going to be a learning curve for you if you are going to recover the data, most of the work you will be doing will be low-level and very often time consuming

Comment: Ok thanks for your help. Luckily I had backed up the most important stuff, but there's other non-critical stuff there I would really like to recover, so I'll give it a go.

Answer (score 0):

Steve's answer is a good one. I'd like to add a bit to it:

- In the distant past, the term "format" often referred to *low-level* formatting, which meant defining where on the disk individual sectors began and ended. Ubuntu still includes a tool, called `fdformat`, which performs this type of low-level formatting on floppy disks. To avoid confusion, many older tools and documentation eschewed the term "format" when referring to higher-level operations, instead using terms like "create a filesystem." Modern hard disks are low-level formatted at the factory and it's difficult or impossible to re-do those operations. Thus, you're only likely to deal with a high-level format (such as creating a filesystem) today. Even writing zeroes to the entire disk using a tool like `dd` does not affect the low-level format.
- Deleting a partition means deleting a handful of bytes on the disk that define where the partition begins and ends. Most partitions are just areas on the disk that hold the *real* data structure of interest -- the *filesystem.* When you delete a partition, the filesystem data structures are normally untouched. (Details depend on the tool you used to delete the partition, though. Some might deliberately wipe or damage filesystem data structures in the interests of security, but this is rare.) Thus, a deleted partition can often be recovered with a tool like [TestDisk,](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) which searches for filesystem data structures and creates a new partition table entry that points to what it finds. When you create a new filesystem, though, the filesystem data structures are at least partially overwritten. Some data structures normally remain, though, as will most of the files -- they'll just be scattered about with nothing pointing to them, as Steve describes.
- In addition to the tools that Steve mentioned, [PhotoRec](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec) is the go-to Linux tool for data recovery when filesystem data structures are toast (as after creating a new filesystem over an old one). PhotoRec can often recover individual files, but they usually lack helpful metadata such as their original filenames, so you can end up with an astounding mass of random files, most of which won't be of any value to you. Imagine searching a haystack for a few gold needles. That's what you'll be doing if you need to use such tools. I've heard that some Windows tools do a better job of recovering filenames from NTFS volumes, but I've never looked into this in detail.
- A complication to all of this is in SSDs. On a hard disk, sectors have more-or-less fixed locations on the disk platters. (A rare exception is when a sector goes bad; it can then be mapped out and replaced by another one held in reserve for this eventuality.) With SSDs, sectors can be remapped by the drive's electronics. This is especially true if [TRIM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trim_(computing)) is used. This feature enables an OS to tell the SSD which sectors it is or is not using, and the SSD can then adjust its mappings, consolidate and wipe unused sectors, etc., to improve reliability and efficiency. If you issued an `fstrim` command or mounted the filesystem with the `discard` option after creating the new filesystem, you activated TRIM, which means that the SSD may have scrambled the mapping of actual storage areas to sector numbers and perhaps wiped data. This will make data recovery much harder. If you did not do either of these things, data might be as recoverable as it would be on a conventional hard disk. All that said, my experience recovering data from SSDs is quite limited, so I don't know how much of an extra challenge TRIM would pose in reality.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The partition I accidentally formatted (to ext4) was a LUKS partition. Can testDisk recover this? I'm trying to figure out if there is a way to enter the password and mount it first because if I don't there will nothing to search for.

Comment: Was informed that my upvotes for your post are recorded but don't show publicly because I have too small reputation. lol

Comment: What do you mean low-level formatting can not be easily done?
Have you ever done anything like dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda?
This is what I consider a low level format, but please educate me otherwise
AFAIK a brand new disk is completely zero'ed out, and performing an operation like this clears all data on the disk, this is excluding S.M.A.R.T. data of course, which is stored elsewhere

Comment: @pr88, *if* you deleted the partition rather than writing a new filesystem to it, it's conceivable that TestDisk could recover the partition; but as you say you wrote a fresh ext4 filesystem to the partition, it's *very* unlikely that you'll be able to recover any data from that partition. Encrypting data makes it *very* difficult to recover the data if any of it has been damaged, and writing a new filesystem over the encrypted data qualifies as damage.

Comment: @Steve, no, writing zeroes with `dd` is *not* a low-level format of the device. This operation *will* wipe the data *you store* on the disk, but this is effectively a high-level format. "Beneath" the data you can see, there's data that describes where sectors begin and end, along with other low-level features. You have no access to this data in modern hard disks. Very old hard disks and floppy disks, though, required low-level formatting in which the sectors themselves were defined, and this is what `fdformat` and similar tools did (and still do, if you happen to have a floppy disk).

Comment: @Rod Smith Thank you for your response. Going by your response I guess my stuff is gone for ever. Oh well.

Comment: @RodSmith are you talking about cylinder, head, sector, I guess geometry information would have a format of its own, I'm having flashbacks of entering this data in to my BIOS on my 80386

Comment: @Steve, partly, yes; but it's not just entering the CHS values in the BIOS setup utility -- it's actually *preparing a disk* with a low-level tool like (once again) `fdformat`. (Please read its `man` page.) This was pretty common with floppy disks, although the DOS and Windows tools tended to combine low-level and high-level format operations, thus hiding the distinction. With floppies, there were utilities that would enable squeezing a few extra KiB onto a disk by adjusting sector sizing -- something that's possible only by adjusting the low-level format details.